# Receive Binary Data and Write (Socket Programming in C++)

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, binary, sstream

i have created server and client to communication. Client sends binary data of image then server receives it and writes to file. I have pasted necessary code below.

```
            std::stringstream binStr;

            bytes_received = recv(new_sd, &binStr, sizeof(binStr) ,0);
            std::cout << binStr << std::endl;

            char buff[1024*1024];
            std::string image;

            while (!binStr.eof())
            {
                binStr.read(buff, sizeof (buff));
                image.append(buff, binStr.gcount());
            }

            int id = 1;
            std::stringstream ss2;
            ss2 << id;
            std::string str2 = ss2.str();
            std::ofstream img(str2.c_str(),std::ios::binary);
            std::cout << image.c_str() << std::endl;
            img.write(image.c_str(), image.length());
```

this code creates file with name as id , but its an empty file. How can i fix it?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: sorry forgot the question :) , added to first message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `recv()` into a `std::stringstream` like you are attempting to.  You have to `recv()` into a buffer first and then you can copy that data into your `std::stringstream` afterwards.  However, you are using the `std::stringstream` only as an intermediate to get data into your `buff` buffer, and then from there to a `std::string`. You can get rid of the `std::stringstream` altogether and `recv()` directly into `buff` instead.  I would even go as far as getting rid of the `std::string` altogether as well, as you do not really need it:

```
int id = 1;
std::stringstream ss2;
ss2 << id;
std::ofstream img(ss2.str().c_str(), std::ios::binary);

// 1MB is a lot to put on the stack, use the heap instead
std::vector<char> buff(1024*1024);
do
{
    bytes_received = recv(new_sd, &buff[0], buff.size(), 0);
    if (bytes_received < 0)
        break; // ERROR!

    if (bytes_received == 0)
        break; // DISCONNECT!

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes_received; ++i)
        std::cout << buff[i];
    std::cout << std::endl;

    img.write(&buff[0], bytes_received);

    // TODO: if reached the end of the image, stop here
}
while (true);
```

Unless the sender closes its end of the connection after sending the image data to you, then you need a way to know when the end of the image has been reached.  The sender will have to send the image data length to you so you know when to stop reading.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i don't know how to implement your TODO. I have sent "size_t imageSize" from client.

Comment: I changed write part and problem solved. `img.write(&buff[8], bytes_received);` Opened image file with notepad and saw 8 x "/00" characters. Don't know how did that chars put there.

Comment: Why did you make that change? That will break the code. It needs to be `&buff[0]`. As for the TODO, are you creating the sender that is sending the image data? If so, then you need to update it to send the image data length before sending the image data. Otherwise, you need to determine how the sender is doing that. If no length is being sent, the only way to detect the end of the data is by the connection being closed.

Comment: I have changed buff[0] because the images in sender(client) and receiver(server) are different. If i open images with vim(or notepad) , received image has extra 8 `/00` characters. Then i started from buff[8] To ignore these characters.

Comment: Those first 8 bytes are likely important or else the sender would not be sending them in the first place. If you must start at the 8th byte then you must subtract 8 from `bytes_received` or else you will read 8 bytes past the edge of `buff` when you `write()` it, thus writing random data to your file (if not causing an access violation error).

Comment: I am not using bytes_received inside of write method. I sent imageSize before send image. Thanks for your help.